# How to display tweets on an html page based on a dynamic search query

Tags: html, node.js, twitter, word-cloud

I am creating a webpage where user can enter any search term like "Earthquake" or "Election" etc and all the latest tweets based on the search term should be displayed on my html page.
Also, I want to create a word cloud for the most frequently occurred words on the tweets corresponding to the search word.

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'xxxxx'
   , consumer_secret:      'xxxxx'
   , access_token:         'xxxxx'
   , access_token_secret:  'xxxxx'
  })

 T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'earthquake', count: 1000 }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
 })
```

I would like to know how can I display the results in my html page. I was able to see twitter feeds by embedding a timeline onto my page(by creating a widget). But that is for a single query and is not dynamic.

Any idea? Please help. Thanks

Comment: based on the fact that you're using require('twit'), i'm going to assume you're using node.js? how familiar are you with node?

Comment: i ask so i know how detailed i should be with my response :)

Comment: Hi Nick, I am not an expert, but I understand and can work with nodejs with little research. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're not opposed to creating your own server with [express](http://expressjs.com/) you could do something like this: ( this is a video i made for a student of mine recently with a similar question using the same twit module ) https://vimeo.com/146306473 ( password: koy )

**UPDATE**

in that video, the client side index.html view creates an array of tweets from the innerHTML of the element populated with the tweets from the server like this:

```
data = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;
twArr = data.split(',');
```

you can instead create an array of each word from that same innerHTML by splitting the string at every space ( " " ) rather than every "," like this:

```
twArr = data.split(' ');
```

and then pass that into the d3 example like this...

```
.words(twArr.map( ...etc
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can split those tweets into words and just take the words which occur more frequently and pass that to D3js inorder to create a wordcloud. I referred to this link : http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/rutpj/light/ But, looks like I have to pass the words in json format? Any idea?

Comment: looks like the words are passed as an array, i'll edit the answer above with code for how you might do this

Comment: Thanks Nick. Could you please advice me on how I can remove punctuations and words like 'A', 'to', 'is' etc.. I just want to display a cloud with words that occur more frequently on the latest tweets.

Comment: if you've got a specific list of words you want to remove you can include them in a separate array and then use a function like this http://jsfiddle.net/ueL3n6d6/1/ to create a new array that removes that list of words to remove from the original array

Comment: hi @Katie did this work out for you? if so you should accept the answer for future users who stumble upon the question :)